# Minimax Tic-Tac-Toe Python Logical Issue

Tags: python, recursion, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

Having trouble with the logic of my minimax function. All other helper functions are tested and performing properly. When the AI of my tic-tac-toe game reaches the minimax function, the error I get is `"TypeError: '\<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'"`, so I'm guessing it's an issue with comparing v and the new_action tuple that is returned? So far unable to diagnose the issue in the logic of minimax. Min player O has a utility of -1, 0 for a tie, and max player X has a utility of 1. (`"state"` is the 2D array of the game board)

```
def minimax(state):
    def max_value(state):
        if terminal(state): return utility(state)
        v = float('-inf')
        new_action = None
        for action in actions(state):
            temp = max(v, min_value(result(state, action)))
            if temp > v:
                v = temp
                new_action = action
        return new_action
        
    def min_value(state):
        if terminal(state): return utility(state)
        v = float('inf')
        new_action = None
        for action in actions(state):
            temp = min(v, max_value(result(state, action)))
            if temp < v:
                v = temp
                new_action = action
        return new_action

    if terminal(state): return None

    if player(state) == X: max_value(state)
    else: min_value(state)
```

I've looked into the logic of minimax functions and pseudocode but haven't been able to make progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- The final `if..else` statement in `minimax` doesn't return anything, so `minimax` always returns `None`
- There is a mix up of return value for `min_value` and `max_value`. On the one hand, the expression `max(v, min_value(result(state, action)))` expects `min_value` to return a *value* (score), while on the other hand, `return new_action` returns the *action* (move) -- which the ultimate caller of `minimax` would also like to get.

The solution is to have `min_value` and `max_value` return a *pair* so the caller has both the value (score) and the action (move). For that reason I would also rename these functions to `minimize` and `maximize` (as they don't only return the *value*)

Note that there is no need to call `max` or `min` where you have it. Also, there is no need to check for a terminal state in the main body of the `minimax` function, as this is the first check that the inner functions make anyhow.

```
 def minimax(state):

    def maximize(state):
        if terminal(state):
            return (utility(state), None)
        best = (float('-inf'), None)  # Pair of value and action
        for action in actions(state):
            temp = minimize(result(state, action))  # We get a pair
            if temp > best:
                best = (temp, action)
        return best  # Return the pair of value and action
        
    def minimize(state):
        if terminal(state):
            return (utility(state), None)
        best = (float('inf'), None)  # Pair of value and action
        for action in actions(state):
            temp = maximize(result(state, action))  # We get a pair
            if temp < best:  # Compare pairs by value first
                best = (temp, action)
        return best  # Return the pair of value and action

    # Choose which function to call
    optimize = (minimize, maximize)[player(state) == X]
    return optimize(state)[1]  # Extract the move from the pair and return it
```

If `action` objects are not comparable, then compare the first pairmembers only, like `if temp[0] < best[0]`.

The statement to set `optimize` is short for:

```
if player(state) == X:
    optimize = maximize
else:
    optimize = minimize
```

As functions are objects like other types are, you can just assign them and then call them (as `optimize` references a function).

Without that extra name `optimize` you'd do:

```
if player(state) == X:
    return maximize(state)[1]
else:
    return minimize(state)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did have to alter the temp and best comparisons to temp[0] and best[0] so that the first values of the tuples (the scores) are being compared. After that adjustment, it all worked. Also, I am not familiar with the function selection syntax of the last two lines. If you could elaborate on that it would be great!

Comment: Added some explanation.